# PHP Regex to convert text before colon to link

Tags: php, regex

I need to find the first occurance of a colon ':' and take the complete string before that and append it to a link.

e.g.

```
username: @twitter nice site! RT www.google.com : visited!
```

needs to be converted to:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/username">username</a>: nice site! RT www.google.com : visited!
```

I've already got the following regex that converts the string @twitter to a clickable URL:

E.g.

```
$description = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $description);
```

Any ideas : )

Comment: Is the name always at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Yes always at the start.

Comment: Do `username:` and `@twitter` should have to be 2 different links? Because after conversion the `@twitter` disappears in your example.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use string manipulation for this, rather than regex, using [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
$username = strstr($description, ':', true);
$description = '<a href="http://twitter.com/' . $username . '">' . $username . '</a>'
             . substr($description, strlen($username));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$regEx = "/^([^:\s]*)(.*?:)/";
$replacement = "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\1\" target=\"_blank\">\1</a>\2";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code, but it should work as is. Basically you need to capture after @twitter too.

```
$description = preg_replace("%([^:]+): @twitter (.+)%i", 
    "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>: \\2", 
    $description);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work -

```
$description = preg_replace("/^(.+?):\s@twitter\s(.+?)$/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>: \\2", $description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer to your question:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^(.*?):/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">$1</a>:', $string);
```

But I assume that you are parsing twitter RSS or something similar. So you can just use `/^(\w+)/`.