# PHP regular expression: Get all text from start of string to the ' : '

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
> [PHP Regex to convert text before colon to link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539545/php-regex-to-convert-text-before-colon-to-link) 
> [Return the portion of a string before the first occurrence of a character in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766301/return-the-portion-of-a-string-before-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character-in-php)

I need to get the username from a [Twitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed.

I am returning this data from the feed as the title, and I want to extract the username.

```
UsernameIwanttoget:This is the Twitter message....
```

So basically, get all the text before `:`.

Comment: @hakre: This is not by any stretch a duplicate of that question.

Comment: `strtok($mystring, ":")` -- job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pos = strpos($text, ':');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $username = substr($text, 0, $pos);
    $message  = substr($text, $pos + 1);
}
```

You don't really need regular expressions here. Regular expressions are slow and not easily understandable if you're not familiar with them, so you'd better go with a string function when you can.

You should use [cdhowie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997328/php-regular-expression-get-all-text-from-start-of-string-to-the/6997396#6997396) instead.

Comment: +1 It's faster too without regex. Only use regex when it adds value.

Comment: just a note: given the case that your text is something like "name<space>: text" you will also end up having the whitespace

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this with `explode()`:

```
$pieces = explode(':', $text, 2);

if (count($pieces) != 2) {
    # Malformed message
}

$username = $pieces[0];
$message = $pieces[1];
```

If you want the message too, extracting both pieces at once this way is (IMO) a bit more readable than using a regular expression or `substr`.

If there is optional whitespace padding, you might consider running the result strings through `trim()`.

Comment: This is far cleverer than my answer.

Comment: @yokoloko: Both are valid approaches though.  If the OP only wants the username, your approach will be a bit faster and use slightly less memory.  Though I would suggest editing your example to gracefully handle the case where there is no colon in the text.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the limit parameter for explode. Damn cool! `If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.`

Answer (score 2):

explode() would be better. You can then make use of both the username and tweet.

```
$tweet = explode(":", $text);
```

`$text[0]` will give you the username, and `$text[1]` would give you the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression for such a simple task. Just search for the colon and extract the characters up so far:

```
$str = 'UsernameIwanttoget:This is the twitter message...';
$pos = strpos($str, ':');
if (!$pos)
{
  // Something went wrong: $str doesn't have the expected format!
}
else
{
  $username = substr($str, 0, $pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Example:

```
$stuffIWant = "UsernameIwanttoget:This is the Twitter message....";
$pieces = explode(":", $stuffIWant);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*)(\\s)*:/", $string, $result);
```

This will get you all alphanumeric characters (and the dash), but it will not match any spaces between the text and the ":"

So `$result[1]` will have the matched string.

Answer (score 0):

[What yokoloko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997328/php-regular-expression-get-all-text-from-start-of-string-to-the/6997359#6997359) and [Flinsch said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997328/php-regular-expression-get-all-text-from-start-of-string-to-the/6997389#6997389) is true, but for the answer's sake:

```
$str = 'UsernameIwanttoget:This is the Twitter message...';
preg_match('/([A-Z0-9]+)[^\s]:/i', $str, $matches);

// If something could be matched, $matches[1] contains the matched part
$username = $matches[1];
//etc...
```